# Matlab commands (with some prior working)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matlab

I am not too sure how to input the next two questions into Matlab. Would anyone know how to do this?

Consider individuals for whom the Mosteller formula and the du Bois & du Bois
formulae are both accurate.

Equation 1: Mosteller: sqrt hw/3600

Equation 2: du Bois and du Bois: 0:007184 h^0.725 w^0.425

1. Use the two formulae to get a formula for w as a function of h. Use Matlab to
   plot w for h between 0 and 200 cm.
2. Use the two formulae to get an expression for surface area as a function of h.
   Use Matlab to plot the surface area for h between 0 and 200 cm.

I'm not too sharp with Matlab just yet!

Comment: These are more algebra problems than matlab programming problems. Are you having trouble carrying out the algebra? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: Ya, I'm stuck on the last two questions which require both algebra and Matlab.

Comment: All I see is $0.007184 \cdot h^{0.725} w^{0.425}$. Is there more to it? Is there an equals sign missing?

Comment: Is it perhaps $A=\sqrt{hw/3600}= 0.007184 \cdot h^{0.725} w^{0.425}$?

Comment: They are two separate equations. All they do is simply estimate a persons surface area by using a persons height and weight.

Comment: Yes, but there has be an equal sign somewhere. You cannot solve for $w$ in terms of $h$ if you only have one side of the equation. Review your post and make sure that things are easily understandable for someone reading it with no background information. For example, this is not an equation: "du Bois and du Bois: 0:007184 h^0.725 w^0.425"

Answer (score 0):

Here is some help for the first item. I am assuming that you are given

$$
A = \sqrt{ { hw \over \delta } } = \alpha h^{\beta} w^{\gamma}
$$

and that you want to solve for $w$ in terms of $h$. Square both sides and rearrange to get $w$ by itself:

$$
hw = \delta \alpha^2 h^{2\beta} w^{2\gamma} \\
\Rightarrow w=\left( \delta \alpha^2 h^{2\beta-1} \right)^{ 1 \over {1-2\gamma}}
$$

To plot this in matlab, try something like the following:

```
h = 0:1:200;
w = ( delta * alpha^2 * h.^(2*beta-1) ).^(1/(1-2*gamma));
plot( h, w );
```